# Conectarse y crear carpeta desde FTP C#

Tags: c#, mvc

Apenas empece a trabajar con esto y soy un poco novato en esto, estoy trabajando con MVC, C# y lo que estoy intentando es realizar una conexión a FTP

Lo que hago primero es recibir un formulario y hago una validación de que la carpeta exista de lo contrario crearla

```
//verificar si existe directorio si no crearlo//

            string ruta = @"..\Imagenes_levantamiento\";
            string rutafinal = ruta + IdUnico + @"_" + idkey + @"\";
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(ruta))
            {
                //Conexion a FTP y crear la carpeta
                //AQUI AYUDA A CONEXION Y CREAR CARPETA CON FTP*******
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string NombreArchivo = proyedesc + @"_" + idkey + @"_" + fileName;

                BLL.GuardaLevantamiento(IdLevantamiento, id, Edificio, Elemento, NombreArchivo, Descripcion, latitud, longitud, Usuario, nivel, area, TipoProyecto);
            }
            else
            {
                    //proviconal en lo q se crea carpeta//

                    string NombreArchivo = proyedesc + @"_" + idkey + @"_" + fileName;
                BLL.GuardaLevantamiento(IdLevantamiento, id, Edificio, Elemento, NombreArchivo, Descripcion, latitud, longitud, Usuario, nivel, area, TipoProyecto);



            }
```

Lo que intento es que en la ruta:
d:\DZHosts\LocalUser\IncaMexico\"nueva carpeta"

se cree la carpeta mediante FTP

Estuve buscando en la web pero nada me ha funcionado y/o no he podido implementarlo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un webClient para guardar en FTP

Aqui un ejemplo:

//Se instancia la conexion al FTP

```
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usuarioFtp"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passwordFtp"]);

                foreach (var item in filesToFTP)//Por cada archivo se envia al FTP
                {
                    client.UploadData((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlServidor"] + fileName ), "STOR", item.byteArray);
                }
            }
```

ten en cuenta que te pide tu archivo en un arreglo de bytes (byteArray)

Puedes usar esto:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

Crear Carpeta:

```
    string ftpURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlServidor"];

    string filename = (ftpURI + filename);
    FtpWebRequest ftpReq = WebRequest.Create(filename) as FtpWebRequest;
    ftpReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
    ftpReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "password");
    FtpWebResponse ftpResp = ftpReq.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
```

Comment: ok lo pruebo, pero esto me ayudara a crear la carpeta si no existe?

Comment: Para crear necesitas usar un webrequest. Edite mi respuesta

Comment: ftpURI me lo asigna en null ... mi url es string ftpURI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ip"]

Comment: Si, claro yo puse un ejemplo ya que no mencionas la ip